# Make tag cloud links consistent

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tags

I'm using this code: 
`<?php wp_tag_cloud( array( 'taxonomy' => 'channels') );?>`
To display custom taxonomy as a cloud tag.
How can display with all links being the same size? I can't seem to override the inline styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about passing the `smallest` and `largest` arguments to `wp_tag_cloud()` and making them both the same?

```
<?php 
wp_tag_cloud( 
    array( 
        'taxonomy' => 'channels',
        'smallest' => '1',
        'largest' => '1',
        'unit' => 'em',
    )
);?>
```

Update: use `get_terms()` to get multiple taxonomy terms:

```
<?php $terms = get_terms(array('channels', 'stations'));
if (is_array($terms)) : ?>
<ol>
    <?php foreach ($terms as $term) : ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term) ?>"><?php echo $term->name ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. How could I adjust it to support a second taxonomy? I.E. Show the tags for channels and stations.

Comment: @Sam It's starting to sound like maybe you should use `get_terms()` instead of a tag cloud. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Strip the inline CSS with a filter on `'wp_tag_cloud'`:

```
add_filter( 'wp_tag_cloud', 'wpse_56312_clean_tag_cloud' );
function wpse_56312_clean_tag_cloud( $tags )
{
    return preg_replace( "~ style='[^\']*'~", '', $tags );
}
```